# Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future<List<dynamic>> Function()'

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, provider

I am new to flutter and I really have no idea to to use sqlite database with `provider`. although i have created a todo app with `provider` and I have successfully added a `sqlite database` to it. But while getting data I get error in my `listViewBuilder` widget.

> Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future> Function()'.

Thi is my code.

> database_connection.dart

```
Future<List<Task>>getTasks() async {
    await openDb();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>>maps = await _database.query('tasks');
    print(maps);
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i){
      return Task(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        name: maps[i]['title'],
        date:maps[i]['date'],
        isDone: maps[i]['iscomplete'] == 1 ? true: false,

      );
    });
  }
```

> taskData.dart

```
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {

  final TaskDatabaseManager taskDatabaseManager = new TaskDatabaseManager();


  List<Task> _tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Buy coffee'),
    Task(name: 'Go Shopping'),
    Task(name: 'Go Sleep'),

  ];

//  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks {
//    return UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);
//
//  }

  Future<List>tasks()async {
    return await taskDatabaseManager.getTasks();
  }
```

> task_tile.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return TaskListTile(
                taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,

                isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
                checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
                  taskData.updateTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                },
                deleteCallback: () {
                  taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                },
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
```

any help would be great.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer but more of a suggestion. I personally detest SQL so I typically use some kind of nosql solution like sembast or hive. Hive is pretty easy to understand and comes with a few nice features. You may prefer using one of those instead for your persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving data could be bit tricky as it normally runs asynchronously. Here's my proposed flow.

Retrieve data at the initial state.

```
final List<Task> _tasks;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tasks = taskData.tasks();
}
```

Return a placeholder when data is still loading (normally a loading indicator)

```
if (_tasks == null) {
  return CircularProgressIndicator(
    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(const Colors.white),
  );
}
```

When the data is ready:

```
return TaskListTile(
  taskTitle: _tasks[index].name,
  isChecked: _tasks[index].isDone,
  checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
    taskData.updateTask(_tasks[index]);
  },
  deleteCallback: () {
    taskData.deleteTask(_tasks[index]);
  },
);
```